# iTunes Connect Testflight Internal Testers

Tags: testing, app-store-connect, appcelerator, testflight, beta

Downloading beta app from testflight app gives error at the end, says "Unable to download app at this time" on all my devices.
No error is in itune connect upload. App displayed and received notification on adding new app to testflight beta. But everytime same error.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue, It uploads using iTunes connect fine and allows me to setup internal beta testers, then gives this error when i try to download using the AppStore TestFlight app

Comment: I did some research by reducing the size of the app to 8-10 MB by removing codes (In fact build a parallel app with less code). Found that when the app size is around 10 mb it was working fine and I am able download. But the actual app, when its size is around 30 MB testflight failed to download and gives error. "Unable to download app".     I suspect this is something related to testflight servers timout with large size app. Hopeful apple will fix this before 26th Feb.

Comment: I am seeing this today, March 6 2014, with the 2nd beta test build of an app. The first beta test was 11.5Mbytes and that worked fine. The second is 12.4Mbytes and that is not working.

Comment: i think its something related to your provisional profile. please regenerate the provisional profile and try again

Comment: When the app size is around 8-10 MB it works, so I don't think its related to provisioning profile. I tried that too.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I wasn't using the correct provisioning profile. Very frustrating error that doesn't provide any useful info, and leaves the previous installed version of your test build in a state where it cannot be launched. After I switched my provisioning profile to 'Automatic', bumped the build number, and submitted a new version to iTunes connect I was able to download the new build.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a similar error. I don't know for sure, but I suspect doing things in this order may have something to do with it (this seems to mirror what emrys57 is facing).

1. You have issued a previous TestFlight release (download/install was working).
2. You then submitted that version for formal review for publication in the App Store.
3. While the app submission is still under review, now you uploaded a new TestFlight build with an updated version number (but did not resubmit for App Store review).

It could be that while the app is under review something prevents the download. I seem to recall reading about something like this in one of the guides, but I can't remember where off the top of my head. In my case, as an *internal tester* I even face the error "Unable to download app at this time", regardless of whether I already have a previous version with the same bundle ID already installed or if I don't have the app already installed (i.e., it's fully uninstalled). I wonder if an accepted App Store review will clear up the issue; it doesn't seem like a good idea to resubmit that latest build for further App Store review if the version previously submitted is what you actually want released.

In my case, for the general testing audience, I have a separate bundle ID that is exclusively for beta testing. And that version is never submitted for App Store review (the one that's slated for App Store review I only use for the purpose of smoketesting the upgrade process with internal testers). That bundle ID for beta had to go through the one-time full *TestFlight* external review for the initial TestFlight external beta testing. But I've been able to keep adding new versions to that beta-only bundle ID for subsequent TestFlight releases without an issue.